# Power indicator randomly drops to 0% when turned on

Tags: 20.04, battery, indicator

I'm using a System76 laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 and haven't had issues in two years of usage. However, shortly after I updated to 20.04, my PC suddenly started to turn on with 0% battery, no matter how much it had left when turned off.
It's not a battery drain problem: after experimenting a bit I discovered that when it turns on the PC shows the actual level of battery, then I input the password, unlock it, and suddenly the power indicator drops to 0%. Then I plug it in and after two minutes or so it comes back to the previous level (be it 20%, 70&, 98% or whatever). I tried not plugging it in, thinking it might be a power-indicator problem, but then the laptop will hibernate and won't turn on until plugged in.
Even more puzzling, the issue does **not** happen if I turn airplane mode on before switching the laptop off.

Any help? I'm fairly new to ubuntu so I don't even know what command lines can I run in terminal to identify the problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I also have similar problem with my lenovo Thinkpad t440p whicis more than 4 years old.
But it doesnot drops to zero suddenly. If the charge is 10% within a minute it drops to 6% then again to 3% after that it logs off.
5-6 Months ago I used ubuntu 18.04 lts without any problem.
I think thats due to the battery hardware issue.
You can:

- Try replacing battery. Or check for any hardware driver for battery.
- Try checking battery performance on other versions of ubuntu(18.04)
  or other operating systems.
- Try reinstalling proper and compatible version laptop.